# How to pass and receive parameters in url in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby, i would like to pass parameters in the url and receive it in controller.

I am expecting operation like

```
www.mysite.com/getuser/id/22
```

where getuser is the param name and 22 is its value.

Please provide me if there is any useful links that i can refer to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read everything in the [Rails Guide to Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). There are two main cases there:

- RESTful routes: only use GET, PUT, POST, DELETE. Rails maps that by using the method `resources`. `resources :pages` will lead to the following routes (and URLs) automatically:

  ```
      sites GET    /sites(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"sites"}
            POST   /sites(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sites"}
   new_site GET    /sites/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sites"}
  edit_site GET    /sites/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"sites"}
       site GET    /sites/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"sites"}
            PUT    /sites/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"sites"}
            DELETE /sites/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sites"}
  ```
- Other routes: There is a rich set of methods you can use in your routes file to add additional routes. But keep in mind: If you just want to address a resource, it is better to stick to restful routes. A typical example is_ `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'`. This allows URLs like:

  - `localhost:3000/sites/help`: controller == `SitesController`, action == `help`
  - `localhost:3000/sites/search/something`: controller == `SitesController`, action == `search`, parameter in `params` is `something` under the key `id`. So inside the action `search`, you will find `params[:id]` bound to `"something"`.

Comment: Thanks mliebelt... this answer is very informative for beginners who work around routing in RoR..!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your config/routes.rb file you write:

```
resources :users
```

Then you create the controller:

```
rails g controller users
```

Inside your controller file you have something(contrived) there like :

```
def show 
  my_id_param = params[:id]
end
```

When you go to:
www.mysite.com/user/22

my_id_param will be 22

I think rails guides are quite good resource, just google for them, has ton of good info there.